# How to create a responsive design with CSS only

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I've seen many WordPress themes that adapt to mobile interfaces/smaller screens using only CSS. Any ideas on how it's done?

For example, the theme [Foghorn](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/foghorn) has a sidebar that disappears in a screen less than 750 px wide. I've looked at the code and I'm very sure that it is done with CSS.

I'd like to employ such a design in a website I'm making.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: This site is for more concrete questions. "teach me" type stuff is offtopic.

Comment: Probably done [via `@media` queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use media queries in your CSS.

Example:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    .someClass {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Everything inside that `@media` block will be applied only if the screen width is 750px or smaller.

You can also do things like `min-width` or combining both.